# Need stored procedure or cursor in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012

This query will insert date and count of sales in a table.

```
SELECT 
    replace(CONVERT(varchar(10), DueDate, 112),'-',''),
    count( distinct sale)
FROM 
    sale s 
JOIN  
    Organisation o ON s.Organisationid = o.OrganisationID
WHERE
    CAST(duedate AS DATE) ='1 Jan 2015' 
    AND '01 Jan 2015' BETWEEN StartDateUTC AND EndDateUTC
GROUP BY 
    replace(CONVERT(varchar(10), DueDate, 112),'-','')
```

I want my query to run for each day of the month (Jan-2015) and insert the count of sales for each day in a table.

Is there a way like..

Creating a cursor  OR a LOOP which keeps running with a parameter which has a starting value as 1st jan-2015 and ending value 31st-Jan-2015 and with the first run it insets the count for 1st Jan and the parameter keeps incrementing for a day with every run and finally stops after 31st jan .

And the final result should have a table with count of sales for each days of the month Jan-2015.

For example:

```
    1stJan- 10
    2nd jan -20
    3rd Jan - 15
```

and so on and so forth till 31st Jan

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: You do not need a cursor. Just change your `where` to cover the whole month. Try it and see. PS is `DueDate` a varchar or datetime? you're treating it as both in your code.

Comment: DueDate is a datetime field. I can't use it in where clause as I'm using status on each day if you see my query '01 Jan 2015' between startdateutc and enddateutc. Im using DataVault which contains history and if I use it in where clause it will not give me value as of that day.

Comment: OK. What you need to do is join to a calendar table. A table that basically just has a list of days in it. Then the date column in the calendar table replaces your hard coded '01 Jan 2015'... this is how you do things in a set based fashion instead of using cursors (procedurallly)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using while loop. Use `FromDate` and `ToDate` and increment the `FromDate` until to reach the `EndDate`.  Insert the result into a temp table and select the result after the loop ends from the temp table (`@ResultTable`).

Try some this like this.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '01/01/2015', 
        @EndDate DATE = '01/31/2015'

DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE(DueDate VARCHAR(50), Sales INT)

WHILE (@FromDate <= @endDate)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @ResultTable

    SELECT 
    replace(CONVERT(varchar(10), DueDate, 112),'-',''),
    count( distinct sale)
    FROM 
        sale s 
    JOIN  
        Organisation o ON s.Organisationid = o.OrganisationID
    WHERE
        CAST(duedate AS DATE) ='1 Jan 2015' 
        AND '01 Jan 2015' BETWEEN StartDateUTC AND EndDateUTC
    GROUP BY 
        replace(CONVERT(varchar(10), DueDate, 112),'-','')

    --Incrementing to next date
    SELECT @FromDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FromDate)
END

SELECT * FROM @ResultTable
```

Comment: This is a procedural (RBAR) solution to something that can be done in a set based fashion.